# How may I obtain the same strike through line?

Tags: symbols

How do I produce a symbol which it to $\asymp$ as $\neq$ is to $=$? The objective is to obtain matching strike through lines.

Comment: unicode-math and some packages have `\nasymp` note `\neq` is not = with a strike through it is a distinguished character in the font so you can not use the same / and whether the available negation / look similar to that stroke in \neq depends on the font being used.

Comment: I see. Do you know about a package which may help me?

Comment: you have provided no information for anyone to answer. If you said what font you were using, preferably by providing a small complete test file, someone could probably suggest how to make a matching negated asymp.

Comment: eg [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvudG.png) from `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{stix2}\begin{document}$a\neq b \nasymp c$\end{document}` with pdflatex

Comment: but  you can always ignore the pre-composed negated characters and strike through the normal characters, so `\not\asymp` and `\not=`  both are constructed using the same / but are two overprinted characters each rather than single characters in the generated \pdf.

Comment: My packages are in this vector: ([T1]{fontenc}, [utf8]{inputenc}, [english]babel, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, enumitem, graphicx, hyperref, latexsym,  babel, blindtext, thmtools, bm, [dvipsnames]xcolor, euro, environ).

There appears to be a conflict with the cancel package.

Comment: sorry you need to edit the question to make an example, you can omit irrelevant packages such as bm, blindtext etc

Comment: Your \not does the trick for what I wanted now. The other packages play other roles in the document, except some, as bm, blindtext, which I may have used only temporarily for some purpose.

Comment: sure I meant whe constructing a minimal example, not your actual document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always ignore the pre-composed negated characters and strike through the normal characters, so `\not\asymp` and `\not=` both are constructed using the same `/` but are two overprinted characters each rather than single characters in the generated pdf.